# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: WalletInfo is not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I work with `Spring MVC, Hibernate and MySQL` app. I just changed the XML based bean definition to the Java annotation based definition. So, currently all the files in the project are now in Java and there is no `web.xml` or `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file in the project. Afterwards, when I run the project, I get the error,

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: WalletInfo is not mapped
```

Full error stack is provided below,

```
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: WalletInfo is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3696)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:102)
    at mobi.puut.database.WalletInfoDaoHibernate.getAllWallets(WalletInfoDaoHibernate.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getAllWallets(Unknown Source)
    at mobi.puut.services.WalletServiceImpl.getAllWallets(WalletServiceImpl.java:65)
    at mobi.puut.controllers.BitcoinWalletsController.showBitcoinWallet(BitcoinWalletsController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
```

The project structure is provided,

[image]

The configuration files are here,

**ApplicationConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mobi.puut.controllers"})
class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

//    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
//    public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
//        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
//    }

//    @Bean
//    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
//        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
//        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(5242880);
//        return multipartResolver;
//    }

//    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
//    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
//        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
//        resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
//        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
//        return resource;
//    }

//    @Bean
//    public InternalResourceViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
//        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
//        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
//        bean.setSuffix(".html");
//        bean.setOrder(2);
//        return bean;
//    }
}
```

**DatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mobi.puut.database"})
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"com.form.handler.entities"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

//    @Bean
//    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
//
//        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
//        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
//
//        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.form.handler.entities"});
//
//        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
//        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
//
//        // set the hibernate properties for the project
//        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
//
//        return em;
//    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager txManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet1");
        dataSource.setUsername("testuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("testpassword");

        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**ServiceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mobi.puut.services"})
public class ServiceConfig {

}
```

**WebInitializer.java**

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class, ServiceConfig.class,
                DatabaseConfig.class);

        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher-servlet", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

    }

//  @Override
//  public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
//      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
//      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
//      rootContext.register(ServiceConfig.class, JPAConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
//
//      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
//      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
//
//      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
//      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
//      dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);
//
//      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
//      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
//      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
//      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
//
//  }
}
```

The database is provided below, 
[image]

I have enabled the `Hibernate Support` for the project, but, I feel still suspicious about it, e.g get some red flag in the project where the error started,

[image]

The `WalletInfo` class is provided below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet_info")
public class WalletInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Here I get the from Reversed engineering of the table,

[image]

Whats the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: Well do you have an entity called `Wallet`?  Note that you need to use the name of the _entities_, not tables, in your HQL.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have updated the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have provided the name of the entity and not the MySQL table name. I come here after reading few other question in the forum and they solved it likewise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[]{"com.form.handler.entities"});
```

to

```
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[]{"mobi.puut.entities"});
```

Comment: I started from another project and forget to correct it. It's working now. Thanks a lot and I will accept the answer after few minutes

Comment: @Artin Cheers, much appreciated

Comment: This helps me a lot man. Always did the `XML` based configuration and my boss asked me to change all to Java annotation based configuration. I spent the whole yesterday struggling. Now, I just have to change to an `RESTful` app and then, I'm done

Comment: Take the rest of the day off then